# Using log4net and xUnit

Tags: c#, log4net, xunit

We have some code that emits messages to log4net and would like to see those same messages emitted when we run tests on that code under xUnit.

Is there a way to tell xUnit to start up log4net?  I have modified the .config file for xunit.console  It runs fine, but there is no indication of any logging activity.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when unit testing log4net log calls, a [MemoryAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.MemoryAppenderMembers.html) is used like this:

```
private MemoryAppender testAppender;

[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    testAppender = new MemoryAppender();
    BasicConfigurator.Configure(testAppender);

    // etc    
}

[Test]
public void TestLogging()
{
   // etc

   var events = testAppender().GetEvents();
   Assert.AreEqual(1, events.Count()); 
}
```

Comment: This code would allow to test if log entries are produced, however if I understand OP correctly he just wants to see the output in console window.